# install npm socket.io failure node version < 0.10.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, beagleboneblack

Im trying to install socket.io into my beagleboneblack, system says my node -v is v0.8.22 and for installation should be at least higher than 0.10.0. 
but I can`t upgrade my node.
For installing socket.io, I enter the following text:

```
/usr/bin/ntpdate -b -s -u pool.ntp.org
cd /var/lib/cloud9
npm install socket.io
cp bonescript-socketio/*  /var/lib/cloud9
```

Error message:

```
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-parser/2.3.1
WARN engine object-assign@4.1.0: wanted {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.8.22","npm":"1.2.14"})

ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-ms-0.7.1.tgz


Error message upon completion: 
npm ERR! Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR!     at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.13
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/cloud9
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-0.7.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-0.7.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-0.7.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-0.7.1.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/cloud9/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

for node upgrade I've tried

```
opkg update
```

but server seems to be down..

Appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you type in:

cat /etc/dogtag

you will get a readout. This readout tells you what version of Linux you have on your machine. If you go to http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian, the images are updated regularly for the BBB and BBG boards.

Try to update your image and then upgrade to the newer version of socket.io.

Seth

P.S. If this does not work, please let me know.

Comment: Hi De Funct, appreciate your help, I`ve executed and seems I'm using the latest already, Cloud9 GNOME Image 2013.09.04, Angstrom v2012.12 (core edition), or am I checking the wrong data?

Comment: Hello...some people have stopped using Angstrom and started to use Debian. I am pretty sure that Debian images have newer releases of socket.io that come preinstalled on the board.

Comment: I was just typing out that last edit to let you know that things are evolving. They have had Node Red for some time now and updated images usually have updated characteristics and programs from various sources. If you get bored and you want to check out newer images, see the beagleboard.org site.

Comment: In the end I went for debian in my beaglebone.. :)